# DateObject with DateFormat displays incorrectly in Dataset

Tags: bugs, formatting, dataset, date-and-time

**Bug in 10.4.1 still in 11.0—fixed in 12.1 or earlier**

`DateObject`s with `DateFormat` option appear to have the first date part truncated when displayed in a `Dataset`.

Outside of a `Dataset` the `DateFormat` displays as expected.

```
DateObject[{2007, 1, 20}, DateFormat -> {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}]
```

[image]

However, in a `Dataset` it shows as with the `"Year"` truncated.

```
Dataset[
 AssociationThread[{"Date", "One", "Two"}, 
   {DateObject[{2007, 1, 20}, DateFormat -> {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}], 1, 2}]]
```

[image]

In fact, it truncates the first 4 characters of the formatted string.

Bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

10.4.1 Win 7 Ent SP1.

WRI confirmed bug. CASE:3625692

Answer (score 6):

The result we see is due to a somewhat baffling formatting decision made within the machinery that generates the box form of datasets.  When formatting a date object, it uses `DateString` form.  However, it also expressly checks to see whether the date has three components.  If so, it drops the first four characters from the string form.  This is strange and I am tempted to call it a bug.  It wouldn't hurt to report it to Wolfram.

Here is a direct exhibition of the problem:

```
Dataset`MakeAtomBox[
  TypeSystem`Atom[DateObject]
, DateObject[{2007, 1, 20}, DateFormat -> {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}]
]

(*
    InterpretationBox[TagBox[TooltipBox[StyleBox["-01-20", ...], ...]
*)
```

**Analysis (valid for version 10.4.1)**

The problematic definition can be seen like this:

```
Block[{Dataset`RichBox = HoldForm}
, Dataset`MakeAtomBox[
    TypeSystem`Atom[DateObject]
  , DateObject[{2007, 1, 20}, DateFormat -> {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}]
  ]
]

(*
HoldForm[
  DateObject[{2007, 1, 20}, DateFormat -> ...]
, If[Length[First[DateObject[{2007, 1, 20}, DateFormat -> ...]]] == 3
  , StringDrop[#1, 4] &
  , Identity][DateString[DateObject[{2007, 1, 20}, ...]]
  ]
]
*)
```

or by looking for the `DateObject` definition in the output of:

```
Dataset;
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions[Dataset`FormattingAtomic`PackagePrivate`abox]
```

**Work-around**

A quick fix, which will void your warranty, is to replace the problematic definition:

```
Dataset`FormattingAtomic`PackagePrivate`abox[DateObject, x_DateObject] :=
    Dataset`RichBox[x, DateString[x]]
```

Giving:

```
Dataset[
 AssociationThread[{"Date", "One", "Two"}, 
   {DateObject[{2007, 1, 20}, DateFormat -> {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}], 1, 2}]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Comment: No interest in voiding my warranty.  However, I think the developer may have decided to drop the first 4 characters since the default date format starts with the short form of the day name ("Mon", "Tue" , etc.).  They may have decided that they were helping everyone out by removing it.

Comment: Adding four spaces to the front ( `DateFormat ->{"    ", "Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}` ) is a less scary proposition.