# Inconsistent display of DateObjects in Dataset

Tags: dataset, date-and-time

This question is similar issue to [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117768/dateobject-with-dateformat-displays-incorrectly-in-dataset).

<|"a" -> DateObject[{2014, 1, 14}], 
  "b" -> {DateObject[{2015, 3, 23}], 
    DateObject[{2015, 3, 30}]}|> // Dataset

[image]

The formatting is the same if the Keys and Values are interchanged. Personally I prefer the cleaner version with no calendar icon.

Is there an option to force Lists (and other structures) involved DataObject to be formatted as atomic?